# How to connect results from an SQL query to the navigation bar with VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, navigationbar

I have a basic question about using a database with Visual Basic.
I'm using a OleDb connection. I have dragged and dropped editboxes
from the DataDource view. This automatically places the table navigation-
bar on the form. When I run it this works fine. 
However I want to be able to search within the table, with an SQL statement.
How can I connect the results from the SQL query to the navigation bar,such that
the editboxes automatically take the values of the record without having to
assign every textbox manually?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This little snippet seems to work, although you have to specify the Sort columns for your table, and if you want to sort by multiple fields then on the Find call you pass an array of Object() types that correspond to the values you are searching for (in the order of the Sort values.  Let me know if it works for you or if you have any other questions about it.

```
'**** Sample table structure for Database1Dataset.Table1
'   Col1        Col2        Col3
'(row)  "Row1.Col1" "Row1.Col2" "Row1.Col3"
'(row)  "Row2.Col1" "Row2.Col2" "Row2.Col3"
'(row)  "Row3.Col1" "Row3.Col2" "Row3.Col3"

Dim dv As DataView = Me.Database1DataSet.DefaultViewManager.CreateDataView(Database1DataSet.Table1)
dv.Sort = "Col1"

Me.Table1BindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position = dv.Find("Row2.Col1")
```

Here is an example with multiple sort columns

```
Dim dv As DataView = Me.Database1DataSet1.DefaultViewManager.CreateDataView(Database1DataSet1.Table1)
Dim FindValues(1) As Object

dv.Sort = "Col1,Col3"

FindValues(0) = "Row2.Col1"
FindValues(1) = "Row2.Col3"

Me.Table1BindingNavigator.BindingSource.Position = dv.Find(FindValues)
```